# How to parse different JSON schemas that contain similar data?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, oop

So let's say I have the two following schemas where I send a message to a websocketstream and receive a message back containing similar data.

```py
# First Schema
x_sent = {"Product": {"id": "123"}}

x_received = {"properties": {
    "id": {"type": "number"},
    "color": "green"}}

# Second Schema
y_sent = {"Item": {"Product": {"uid": "123"}}}

y_received = {"configs": {
    "id_number": "123",
    "type": "int"},
    "colour": "green"}
```

If I want to distinguish between the two streams I could filter for the message contents:

```py
if msg == "properties":
    use_schema_a()
if msg == "configs":
    use_schema_b()
```

But that's not very DRY if the amount of different schemas grows. I could also do something like this:

```py
msg_routing = {"properties": use_schema_a,
               "configs": use_schema_b}

if msg:
    msg_routing[msg]()
```

But then I'd still be making functions for every schema! I feel like I'm missing something (conceptually). I'd love to make a general class that handles the sending and receiving of messages and only have the stream-specific filtering data in a type of config file.

It could look something like this:

```py
{"schemaA": {"name": "service_ABC", "color": "properties.color", "send_id":"Product:id"},
 "schemaB": {"name": "service_DEF", "color": "configs.colour", "send_id":"Item:Product:uid"}}
```

Like in the examples above, the data I need would be the same (`green` in this example). The `ID` I need to send to get that data is also similar (`123` in this example).

So if I know the schema of the data I need to send and receive, how do I dynamically build something that understands that schema?

To give you a clear example of a starting point:

```py
def on_message(received_msg):
    # The unparsed message we receive is something like
    #      {"properties": {
    #     "id": {"type": "number"},
    #     "color": "green"}}

    # Do our message filtering/parsing

    handle_message_contents(service_name, color)
```

Comment: What are you receiving? It doesn't look like a schema. Why are they so different? It'd be way better if you could just standardize the response messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to use the schema to create a message. If you create your schemas for example like this:

```py
schemas = {
  "service_ABC": {
    "send": {
      "id": ["Product", "id"],
    },
    "receive": {
      "color": ["properties", "color"],
    },  
  },
  "service_DEF": {
    "send": {
      "id": ["Item", "Product", "uid"],
      "cond": ["Item", "Condition"],
    },
    "receive": {
      "color": ["configs", "colour"],
    },
  },
}
```

you can then use a method that, when supplied the name of the service and the correct arguments, can build the data dictionary to be sent:

```py
def build_request(service, **kwargs):
  request = dict()
  for attribute, path in schemas[service]["send"].items():
    second_to_last_level = request
    last_level = request
    for level in path:
      second_to_last_level = last_level
      last_level = last_level.setdefault(level, dict())
    second_to_last_level[level] = kwargs[attribute]
  return request
```

This way you can add different parameters to be sent directly into the schema. See some examples:

```py
build_request("service_ABC", id="123") == {
  "Product": {
    "id": "123"
  }
}

build_request("service_DEF", id="123", cond="New") == {
  "Item": {
    "Product": {
      "uid": "123"
    },
    "Condition": "New"
  }    
}
```

Next, you need to identify where the message is coming from. Best way to do that would be somewhere upstream and pass it to your "schema processor". If you have no way of getting that information alongside your message (which I doubt), you can use one of your proposed approaches.

Once you know what service the message has come from (and therefore which schema to use, you can process the message in a similar way as building the request.

```py
def process(service, msg):
  result = dict()
  for attribute, path in schemas[service]["receive"].items():
    value = msg
    for field in path:
      value = value[field]
    result[attribute] = value
  return result
```

Again, see example:

```py
x_received = {
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "color": "green"
  }
}
process("service_ABC", x_received) == {
  "color": "green"
}
```

If you are really unable to keep the `service` variable around to pass it to `process()`, then I think the best approach would be the one with `msg_routing`. You could have this as a separate dictionary or even add it to the `schemas`. Alternatively, you could always check in `process()` whether you got what you were expecting and if not try to apply the next schema:

```py
def process(msg):
  for service, schema in schemas.items():
    missing_something = False
    result = dict()
    for attribute, path in schema["receive"].items():
      value = msg
      for field in path:
        if not field in value:
          missing_something = True
          break
        value = value[field]
      if missing_something:
        break
      result[attribute] = value
    if not missing_something:
      return service, result
  raise RuntimeError("No schema applies")
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could have helped

Comment: Oh sorry btw. Didn't know I had to manually award the bounty after setting this as my chosen answer. I awarded the bounty just now.

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock No problem, it would have got awarded automatically after a week to the marked answer (if it has 2+ votes). I am okay waiting :D In any case... Thanks!